# Magento 2 : Add Button to Existing Listing Component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, cms-pages, listing-component

I'm creating a custom module trying to add a custom button to CMS pages listing component. How do I add this. I'm using magento 2.2.

Comment: Can you more describe about your requirement. What you are looking.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I've updated as much as I think is relevant, but let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: Are you able to explain your requirement with screen-sort or somethings? Because we required information like which type of listing component you are used and where you want to add button.